# duplicate packets

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I have made two kernel modules for client and server which are transmitting the pkts. and also reciving it. the only problem is that for every packet transmitted from server there are two packets at client side and icmp redirect. I have opened wireshark on both sides the server shows only single packet is transmitted while the on client side it shows two packets. Further there is a problem of icmp redirect(host). how to remove the duplicate packet and icmp redirect?

Comment: You might want to include more details, such as packet dumps from Wireshark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the way you build your MAC headers.

My guess is that you transmit with a broadcast destination MAC. As a result, both the correct machine and another (a router) get the packet. The router sees that you don't need it in order to reach the destination, and therefore sends the redirect.